# How to Parse JSON Object into Array of Tuples?

Tags: json, swift, amazon-s3, aws-sdk, ordereddictionary

In Swift, is it possible to parse a `String` representing a JSON object that only contains strings into an `Array` of tuples `[(String, String)]` (not a `Dictionary<String, String>`)?

I'm programming my iPhone app to forward the presigned post response from my server to Amazon S3, which requires the clients to preserve the ordering of the fields.

This is an example JSON string, with whitespace added for presentation:

```
{
    "policy": "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",
    "x-amz-algorithm": "AWS4-HMAC-SHA256",
    "x-amz-credential": "AKIAIOSFODNN7EXAMPLE/20130721/us-east-1/s3/aws4_request",
    "x-amz-date": "20130721T201207Z",
    "x-amz-signature": "733255ef022bec3f2a8701cd61d4b371f3f28c9f193a1f02279211d48d5193d7"
}
```

According to [Amazon S3: API Reference: Authenticating Requests in Browser-Based Uploads Using POST](http://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonS3/latest/API/sigv4-authentication-HTTPPOST.html), I think it's safe to assume that none of the strings will contain `"`, `:`, or whitespace characters.

So, I guess my question is: How do I parse a String like the one above into an `Array` of tuples `[(String, String)]`?

Comment: Why don't you just implement an [ordered dictionary](http://timekl.com/blog/2014/06/02/learning-swift-ordered-dictionaries/)?

Comment: OK, but then how would I parse a `String` representing a JSON object into an `OrderedDictionary`? Why not just use an `Array` of tuples instead of an `OrderedDictionary`? I've updated my question.